# "grub" entry in BIOS after installing ElementaryOS

Tags: boot, grub, elementary-os, uefi, bios

After installing ElementaryOS, I get the entry (to boot) named "grub". None named ElementaryOS as expected.

Problem is, when going into the grub entry, I get its console (more or less like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/figures/bootscreen2.png)).

Am I supposed to permanently boot from it (and if so, any help about doing so...? I don't have a clue about how this works anyway), or is it a known problem and there's a solution?

(Problems occuring on both a HP Envy dv7 and an Asus Eeebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using `grub-customizer`.